# logging module failed to create file while running through pytest

Tags: python-3.x, logging, pytest, python-logging

I am using below logging config to create a log file. It is working perfectly fine without pytest run, but with pytest, it is failed to create log file.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a',format='%(message)s',level=logging.INFO)
```

Guessing, this above config was overwritten by pytest's config. Hence it failed to create it.

Please suggest how we can execute above logging config and get the log file while running through pytest?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `pytest -p no:logging`